# SharePoint Online Storage Quota

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, quota

Storage Quota is missing from my SharePoint Online admin center. Is this permanently taken away or i don't have permission to it?

I am in a SharePoint Administrator role.

Answer (score 1):

On SharePoint admin center from left quick launch click on settings.

Make sure you Manual is set, if not change it to manual then click Ok.

[image]

Now if you go back to site collections page, select one site collection and you will see the quota option from ribbon.